# Complex Analysis Inequality.

Tags: complex-analysis

Im studying for an exam and this is a practice problem. Not sure where to start or what theorems to even start with.

if $f$ is analytic on $|z|<1$ and $|f(z)|<1$ for $|z|<1$, prove that $$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}\right|\leq \left|1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)\right|,$$

for all $0<|z|<1$.

thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the Schwarz-Pick theorem?

Comment: I have not. I just looked it up and I think the proof is clear from there. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\phi (z)=\frac {z-f(0)} {1-\overline {f(0)} z}$. Then $\phi$  is holomorphic, maps the open unit disk into itself and $\phi(f(0))=0$. Hence $\phi \circ f$ maps the open unit disk into itself, maps $0$ to $0$. By Schwarz Lemma $|\phi \circ f(z)| \leq |z|$ which is precisely what you are trying to prove.